# Bizzre usage of "of" and strange structure of senstence

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Quoating from a Guardian article :

> Thanks to multiculturalism, international movement and technological advances, many communities are now far more **accepting of diversity**

I assume  General meaning of "many communities are now far more accepting of diversity" is nowadays communities are much willing to accept diversity . but , what is this permutation which makes feel **accepting** has a gerundish sense though it doesn't suit in context ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**accepting** in this context is a participial adjective, describing "communities".

accepting (as a participial adjective) of diversity = open to diversity

Comment: Will participial adjective always have "of" in front of  when coming with another adjective . Putting it differently , Is it a rule ?

Comment: No, it's not a rule to use "of" after a participial adjective. There are participial adjectives like "accepting" where "of" is the appropriate preposition to use, though, An example with a different preposition using "interesting": "The biochemistry lecture was interesting to me."

Comment: So it's due to used participial adjective and needs memorising?

Comment: Yes, at first. There might be general rules about which preposition to use, but (personally) I think time and effort would be better spent on reading and listening from a variety of sources to develop your own sense of which prepositions are appropriate for a given situation.

Comment: Thanks for letting me taking a fairly great deal of your time away by answering my questions !